# Installing MongoDB on Raspberry Pi

Tags: mongodb, console, raspberry-pi

i have installed the mongodb exactly like the [tutorial](http://c-mobberley.com/wordpress/2013/10/14/raspberry-pi-mongodb-installation-the-working-guide/) says. But if I run the command `sudo /etc/init.d/mongod start` the console print `Could not find /usr/bin/mongod`. I don't know how I should fix this. Can anyone help?

Comment: The tutorial you have linked is a comparatively *ancient* version of MongoDB. While ARM is not an officially supported platform (as at MongoDB 2.6) the most up to date ARM version I'm aware of is available via Arch Linux ports: http://archlinuxarm.org/packages?search=mongodb. It doesn't make a lot of sense to run MongoDB on a 32-bit Pi unless you have very limited data & performance requirements, though.

Comment: I want test my spring application on a little server. Thats the reason I use MongoDB on my pi.

Comment: I installed it but gave up after finding it to be too slow for the Pi. I'm using NetDB now: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/55693224724/nedb-a-lightweight-javascript-database-using-mongodbs

Comment: I've made a simple auto install script here: https://github.com/vcazan/MongoDB-RPi-Install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The funny thing is that the mongo-db installation took so long that my ssh client denied the connection. So MongoDB wasn't installed. Now all is working.

Comment: This question and answer is useless for community. It doesn't help others to solve their problems.